# How to read ebooks in continuous scrolling mode and save highlights?

Tags: scrolling, ebook, kindle, annotations, calibre

I'm looking for a way to manage my academic workflow for reading e-books in `.epub` or `.mobi` formats on OSX.

My requirements:

- continuous scrolling mode
- ability to highlight text (e.g. in yellow, using a single keyboard shortcut)
- ideally, the ability to make annotations as well

Amazon Kindle reader for OSX offers annotating, but not continuous scrolling mode. Calibre offers continuous scrolling mode, but does not allow highlighting or annotating.

Is there a solution that will allow me to do this?

I'm also open to workarounds, e.g. using Calibre to convert to HTML, then reading the book in a browser---but I would still need the ability to highlight using a single keystroke.

Comment: 3 years later, same question. Sumatrapdf (opensource) doesn't offer highlights, adobe digital edition doesn't allows textflow (but highlights). Even converting in pdf doesn't work since you can't textflow + highlights at the same time (we must chose).

Comment: did you finally find a workaround?

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot iBooks now offers both highlighting, but since it offers continuous scroll only on iOS, not OSX, I'm still converting to PDF and using Skim PDF to highlight and annotate.

Comment: Amazing to get an instant reply after all these years, thanks! Too bad, I'm on windows (skim works only on OS X). Let's wait another 3 years...

Comment: Try [PDF Annotator](https://www.pdfannotator.com/en/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Use Calibre to convert to HTML, use Prince XML to convert to PDF, then use Skim to read in continuous scrolling mode, highlight, and annotate.

Answer (score 0):

I did a brief search, and Adobe Digital Editions should have the features you need.
Unfortunately I can't verify right now 'cause I'm on Linux and it is only available for Win and Mac, but you can try it from yourself and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Adobe Digital Editions doesn't offers scrolling mode